# The $C^\infty(M)$-linearity of the curvature implies that it is defined pointwise

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, curvature

In the second paragraph of this passage from Loring Tu's book:

> [image]

I don't understand why does the $C^\infty(M)$-linearity of the curvature implies that it is defined pointwise ? to be more precise I don't understand why it wouldn't be defined pointwise if it was not $C^\infty(M)$-linear ?

Comment: You can multiply it by bump functions so that defining pointwise is fine. The text is not saying that if it was not $C^\infty(M)$-linear then it wouldn't be pointwise, it's not an if and only if statement. It's just saying you can leverage this fact to show curvature makes sense pointwise.

Comment: From the quote, it seems that Tu is trying to explain that in that section. Did you read the section?

Comment: You are right @Artic char! I continue to read the rest of the chapter and I find the answer to my question, it has to do with the so called local operator. Thank you!